# DNX Core and DNX 4.5 always out of reference when creating a new ASP.net 5 MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create some ASP.net 5 MVC Web Application using VS 2015 CE.
I am always getting error with DNX Core and DNX 4.5 as not being referenced to the project.

I tried changing the project.json file by removing entries in
"frameworks" section and keeping only one at a time from both "dnx451"
and "dnxcore50", still no luck.

I ended up with the large list of compile time error primarily because of the following error.

> **CS1061** 'ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'Database' and no extension method 'Database' accepting a first argument of type 'ApplicationDbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   DemoApp.DNX 4.5.1

and on the same lines

> **CS1061**    'ApplicationDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'Database' and no extension method 'Database' accepting a first argument of type 'ApplicationDbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   DemoApp.DNX Core 5.0

Tried using 'Restore Packages' command as well but nothing happens.

[image]

I dropped the project and re-created, however same things happened again.
As far as I know it worked before and now I don't know what went wrong all of the sudden.

Comment: Do you have `ApplicationDbContext` defined in project - if so please can you add code

Comment: Have you installed ASP.NET 5 RC1 from http://get.asp.net?

Comment: ASP.NET 5 RC1 and all required components are there.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved problem by..

1. Deleting the project.lock.json file (figured out this was not allowing to upgrade and resolve the **References**)
2. Running a DNVM upgrade command from command prompt.